# LocalStorage string always returning undefined JS

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My localStorage string is always returning undefined, no matter what I do? I need help.
Related code snippets:

```
if (window.localStorage.firstVisit !== "false") {
window.localStorage.score = 0;
window.localStorage.name = "";
var origScore = parseInt(window.localStorage.score, 10);
window.localStorage.name;
} else {
var origScore = parseInt(window.localStorage.score, 10);
window.localStorage.name;
}
window.localStorage.firstVisit = "false";
var e = 0;
var fallenHuman = window.localStorage.name;
```

...

```
            console.log(fallenHuman);
        window.localStorage.name = fallenHuman;
        var fallenHuman = window.localStorage.name;
        document.getElementById("namesh").innerHTML = fallenHuman + " - Click to change";
```

Comment: `localStorage.firstVisit`? Did you create that?

Comment: i shouldv'e put the thing to define it before.

Comment: I should have put ```var fallenHuman``` before the first script. This is now solved.

Comment: whatever way you solve your issue make sure not to declare origScore twice using var . You would need to understand Javascript hoisting. better use let or declare origScore variable at the top once and initialize it once inside if & else

Comment: Please create a true [MCVE]. With what you gave, `fallenHuman` should always hold an empty string (`""`)  but never `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, it looks like you are not using `localStorage` correctly. You are setting properties on the `localStorage` object, not actually *in* `localStorage`.

Secondly, you have something like this, which doesn't make any sense:

```
var fallenHuman = window.localStorage.name;
console.log(fallenHuman);
window.localStorage.name = fallenHuman;
```

You are just setting itself to ...itself. `fallenHuman` and `window.localStorage.name` are the exact same thing at all times. This code does nothing.

Example of working with `localStorage` from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

*Sets* an item in `localStorage`

`localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');`

*Gets* an item from `localStorage`

`var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');`

I've never actually seen anyone use `localStorage` in a way that you're using it, but I can assure you, that is not the intended usage of `localStorage`.

**Unrelated your actual issue**: you can probably drop `window` from all your code. You should be able to just do `localStorage.*` and be fine. I'm not sure what your setup is, so if that doesn't work, disregard this.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong. You can use Storage objects just like OP did (by setting/getting on the Storage object directly), with a few gotchas like `.key`, `.length`, `.getItem` etc. which are inherited by their prototype.

Comment: They are updating properties on the `localStorage` object. They need to use `getItem` and `setItem` instead. This would mean when you refresh the page, your data will be gone. If you were to use `localStorage` property by way of get/set item, then the data would be retrievable on page refresh.

Comment: No, the localStorage also can be accessed by keys directly like OP did.

Comment: Didn't know that. `localStorage.testing123 = 4` and then `localStorage.getItem('testing123')` does what you says it does. Not sure why you would do it that way. Probably buried somewhere deep in the spec as all the docs I normally use have no mentioning of this.